# Refer-to Header in SIP REFER message

Tags: twilio, sip

I am trying to use a SIP REFER message to transfer a call on a twilio elestic SIP trunk to a non-twilio number. I am sending a the Refer-to Header with the following format
Refer-To: sip:+15555555555@(destination IP in request line).
I also added a Referred-By header so Twilio had something to use as for ANI on the child call
Referred-By: "SW Test" sip:+16666666666@domain.com
The user info in the Referred-By URL is a number registered with Twilio on the elastic SIP trunk, so I would think that should work, but I keep getting a 403 Forbidden on the child call. I have Call Transfer enabled, Set caller ID as Transferor and Enable PSTN Transfer set on the trunk.
Is there anything else I should be doing?

Comment: Do you have call transfers enabled on your SIP trunk? You can check in the [Twilio console](https://console.twilio.com/us1/develop/sip-trunking/manage/trunks?frameUrl=%2Fconsole%2Fsip-trunking%2Ftrunks%3Fx-target-region%3Dus1).

Comment: I do have call transfers enabled.

Comment: Sorry, you said that in your question. I'm not a SIP expert, so I'm not sure what's happening here. There is a whole [page of documentation on call transfer via SIP REFER](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sip-trunking/call-transfer) have you gone through everything there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a short look to the documentation, it looks like a normal behavior.
sip:+15555555555@(destination IP in request line) is certainly not authorized, the doc is precise on that point :

> Call Transfer to the PSTN In order to transfer a call to the PSTN you
> must include your Trunking Termination Domain for example
> sip:+14152908007@{my-trunk}.pstn.twilio.com or alternatively use a
> Tel-URI for example +14152909007 in the Refer-To header.

Now, I recommend to start with a local tranfer first and later a PSTN transfer in each cases have a look to the call logs.

Comment: That did it! I probably should have read the doc instead of my default manipulation on the header. Thanks!